# Is "will" compulsory for future event?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, tense, future-tense, will-would

Here, both sentences indicate a future event.

What is the difference between the two sentences?

> 1. The meeting starts at 5 o'clock.
> 2. The meeting will start at 5 o'clock.

Is the first sentence grammatically correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Present tenses with future reference](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/123931/present-tenses-with-future-reference)

Answer (score 1):

Will is not compulsory for all future events.

> **The meeting starts at 5 O'clock**
>
> **The meeting will start at 5 O' clock**

Both are correct and may mean almost the same.

But if you say**I think the meeting will start at 5 O'clock** is common.

***I think the meeting starts at 5 O' clock**  is less common

There are many ways of expresing future time without  will or shall

**I am going home tomorrow.( future time)**

**I am going to meet my friend tomorrow.(future time**

**My father retires next year ( future time)**

**I have to submit my report tomorrow( future time)**

**If you went to Mumbai, when would you come back?( future time)**

These are some of the examples only.

Comment: _Will_ is only used in certain circumstances, is almost always contracted (with a pronoun, if possible), and is never required for future reference. As noted, there is no future tense in English, only a set of auxiliaries and constructions used to refer to the future (many of which can also refer to other times).

Comment: "I think the meeting starts at 5 O' clock" sounds fine to me.

Comment: @Justin.I think  is  usually  followed  by           will + verb 1  and  it  is  going  to  happen  but  not  simple  present  according  to  Raymond Murphy.

Comment: "I think the meeting starts at 5 o'clock" is completely correct, and sounds better to my ears than "I think the meeting will start at 5 o'clock" (also correct however).

Comment: According to Raymond Murphy   I think       I am  sure   I do not  think   +  will   verb  1  is natural    but   But  I hope he comes  soon  more  common  than   I hope   he  will come  soon